# How to insert a scroll bar for a particular column in Yii Cgridview

Tags: php, yii

I have a gridview which displays the data of a table. Now in a record, there is a column which contains xml and it contains a large data.

```
<tolist></tolist><cclist><cc><contactpersonname>niraj</contactpersonname><name>niraj</name><email>stgh@gmail.com</email><number>+91.3212365212</number><prefix>Ms.</prefix><contactpersonprefix>Ms.</contactpersonprefix></cc><cc>
```

Now I want to create a vertical scroll bar only to this column where the data is too large.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your gridview cell in `view` file :

```
 array(
            array(
                'name' => 'file_name',
                'header' => 'Filename',
                'filter' => '',
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'fx_wid'
                ),
            ),
```

In site CSS file `style.css`,

```
.fx_wid
{
  width:200px; // as per your wish
  overflow-y:scroll;
  min-height:100px;// if exceeds 100, then scrollbar will appear
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I want to know in which file should I put this css

Comment: You can add in your site css file.

Comment: Did you try my solution?